# I am learning rspec and I have written a spec but it fails partially

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want a way to check if a method raises an error

I have tried the following:

```
expect(described_class.new.convert_to_pdf).to raise_error

class Invoice
    def self.convert_to_pdf
        "Yay"
    end
end

RSpec.describe Invoice do
    describe '#convert_to_pdf' do
        it "Should work" do 
            expect(described_class.convert_to_pdf).to eql("Yay")
        end

        it "should not work on object" do 
            expect(described_class.new.convert_to_pdf).to raise_error
        end
    end
end
```

I want both the test to pass as I want to explain this to my colleague how class method and instance methods differ

Please refer my Error:

1) Invoice#convert_to_pdf should not work on object
     Failure/Error: (described_class.new.convert_to_pdf).should raise_error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `convert_to_pdf' for #<Invoice:0x007fa48e2b2ac0>
 # ./methods.rb:91:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please edit to elaborate, "I have tried the following". What's the problem? Was an exception raised? If so, what was the error message and on what line did it occur?

Comment: Testing that a class method doesn't work on an object is a very unusual test to have. You shouldn't test methods that don't exist because they don't exist and don't need tests. The exception to this is if they *should* exist and you want the test to fail as a reminder.

Comment: @CarySwoveland pleaase refer the error
Invoice#convert_to_pdf should not work on object
     Failure/Error: (described_class.new.convert_to_pdf).should raise_error
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `convert_to_pdf' for #<Invoice:0x007fa48e2b2ac0>

Comment: That information is central to your question so it should be part of the question, not in a comment. Please edit. Don’t forget to say which line of code raised the exception.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that you found most helpful, unless none of them were helpful to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's subtle but there's two ways of defining an `expect` definition. The first is where you supply *a value* or *expression*:

```
expect(x).to be_something
```

Here the expression is evaluated *immediately* and only then does `expect` get a chance to do its thing.

In effect your code looks like:

```
x = described_class.new.convert_to_pdf # Exception happens here
expect(x).to raise_error # Too late, already popped an exception
```

The second form is where you supply *a block*:

```
expect { x }.to raise_error
```

Where here the block is *evaluated by `expect` itself* and its able to capture and inspect any errors that are generated.

When using `raise_error` you want the block form or the exception will slip past `expect`'s rescue mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @tadman It worked and I learned something new :) cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`respond_to`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher) to test if the method is defined on class and/or instance:

```
RSpec.describe Invoice do
  describe '#convert_to_pdf' do
    it "should work on class" do 
      expect(described_class).to respond_to(:convert_to_pdf)
    end

    it "should not work on instance" do 
      expect(described_class.new).to_not respond_to(:convert_to_pdf)
    end
  end
end
```

This way:

- No error will be raised
- Both the tests will pass, and
- You can explain where the method is defined.

**Note:** It doesn't test the return value of the method.

Hope it helps.